# Executable not created in /usr/bin. How to launch the application?

Tags: chrome, sublime-text

I am using Cloudera CDH 5.8 vm. It is a CentOS 6.7

I just installed sublime-text3 and chrome trough these follow commands:

//Sublime text 3 - [Post](https://digitizor.com/install-sublime-text-editor-3-fedora-redhat/)

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dkd903/8ba3f51313c1781cc571/raw/f37b1c18547d086cd45e8b484efc518260106ea9/Install_Sublime_Text_3_64.sh -O install-sublime-text.sh

$ chmod +x install-sublime-text.sh
$ su -c "sh install-sublime-text.sh"
```

Now when I try to access sublime-text through terminal using `$ subl`, as suggested by the post, I have this error:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ subl
/usr/local/bin/subl: line 2: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

In fact, inside **usr/bin** there is no `subl` or any mention to `sublime text`.

I can find sublime text in Desktop menu, Applications > Accessories > Sublime Text 3 link. But when I press it I have the follow error:

```
Could not launch 'Sublime Text 3'
Failed to execute child process 
"/usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text" (No such file or directory)
```

As we can see in the picture this link is trying to find `sublime_text` inside `sublime-text-3`. But it is inside `sublime-text-3/sublime_text_3`.

[image]

I have the same issue to google chrome that I just installed trough `rpm`.
Just downloaded from chrome web site an ran this command:

```
$ sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

And this is what I had at the end of installation:

```
Installed:
  google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:53.0.2785.116-1                                                    

Dependency Installed:
  cups.x86_64 1:1.4.2-74.el6                                                                       
  foomatic.x86_64 0:4.0.4-5.el6_7                                                                  
  foomatic-db.noarch 0:4.0-7.20091126.el6                                                          
  foomatic-db-filesystem.noarch 0:4.0-7.20091126.el6                                               
  foomatic-db-ppds.noarch 0:4.0-7.20091126.el6                                                     
  libmng.x86_64 0:1.0.10-4.1.el6                                                                   
  phonon-backend-gstreamer.x86_64 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5                                                 
  poppler-utils.x86_64 0:0.12.4-10.el6                                                             
  portreserve.x86_64 0:0.0.4-11.el6                                                                
  qt.x86_64 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5                                                                       
  qt-sqlite.x86_64 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5                                                                
  qt-x11.x86_64 1:4.6.2-28.el6_5                                                                   
  qt3.x86_64 0:3.3.8b-30.el6                                                                       
  redhat-lsb.x86_64 0:4.0-7.el6.centos                                                             
  redhat-lsb-compat.x86_64 0:4.0-7.el6.centos                                                      
  redhat-lsb-graphics.x86_64 0:4.0-7.el6.centos                                                    
  redhat-lsb-printing.x86_64 0:4.0-7.el6.centos                                                    

Dependency Updated:
  cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.4.2-74.el6                nspr.x86_64 0:4.11.0-1.el6                       
  nss.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6                      nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6                
  nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6                nss-util.x86_64 0:3.21.0-2.el6                   
  poppler.x86_64 0:0.12.4-10.el6                 poppler-glib.x86_64 0:0.12.4-10.el6              

Complete!
```

Again, I have a chrome link inside Applications > Internet that do noting when I press. I have no mention to Chrome inside `/usr/bin`.

So I don't know what is happening.
Is there something that I am missing while installing these softwares?

Answer (score 1):

What you just downloaded was de script to install sublime-text.
It says:

```
#!/bin/sh
SHORTCUT="[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 3
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=/usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text
Icon=/usr/local/sublime-text-3/Icon/128x128/sublime_text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;"
SCRIPT="#!/bin/sh
if [ \${1} == \"--help\" ]; then
    /usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text --help
else
    /usr/local/sublime-text-3/sublime_text \$@ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi"

curl -L "http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime_text_3_build_3059_x64.tar.bz2" -o "/usr/src/Sublime Text 3.tar.bz2"
cd /usr/src
tar -xvjf "Sublime Text 3.tar.bz2"
cd "Sublime Text 3"
mkdir -pv "/usr/local/sublime-text-3"
mv -fv * "/usr/local/sublime-text-3/"
echo "${SCRIPT}" > "/usr/local/bin/subl"
chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/subl"
echo "${SHORTCUT}" > "/usr/share/applications/sublime-text-3.desktop"

echo "Finish!"
```

What refers to download the tar.bz2 archive with the source code of the program and install it in your system.

Now, aparently it didn't worked because it failed in some of the steps of the script.

You can run the script you downloaded using

```
su -
```

to gain access as root and, after that running the script (assumming you downloaded it in /home/cloudera/

```
sh /home/cloudera/install-sublime-text.sh
```

It would be helpful if you can paste the output of that here, to see if the script ended up installing the required packages or got stuck somewhere.